# Wordpress - custom post types with custom fields, gone from admin menu

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

I followed the below tutorials in order to create a custom post type with custom fields.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-r1b0wA98Ew

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6URWfMTsWPo

This worked great and I added lots of data using the forms I'd created and had the data displaying on the front end of the website.

A week ago, the custom post type disappeared from the Admin Menu but the the data seems to be intact from the front-end point of view.  I posted a message in the CPT UI wordpress forum and got told to simply re-add the post type and re-link the data back up.

My question is HOW do I re-link the data back up?  I have re-added the Custom Post type so its ls listed in the admin menu, but I need to be able to edit the custom posts I have already added.  Can anyone help?  Not getting much help from the Wordpress forum.  Thanks

Comment: Please check the screen options, located above.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is not related to programming. It is more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or the WordPress forums.

Comment: Did you not try ask that on the CPT UI wordpress forum?

Comment: Go to your settings and re-save your permalinks.. JFSAG. Never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS the data is intact in the front end it means the entries are still in database and nothing is lost.

It is correct way to just re-add the missing `post-type` and WordPress will now automatically re-link/re-connect your existing data, since WordPress is storing custom post type in the `wp_posts` table with `post_type` field value to your user-defined value.

Just make sure that the post-type name is same as you used earlier because slight mistake in spelling will lead to data not displayed in admin panel as expected.

You can also post further details which would be helpful to get actual problem found out.

Answer (score 0):

@leetee this has 50/50 chance, experimental and since there is no way to reproduce this behaviour; try exporting your custom post types by using Tools -> Export and then see if you could Import them into a fresh WP install...